# npm install sails-mongo --save not working

Tags: mongodb, npm, sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

I wanted to add `sails-mongo` in my sails project. But when I am trying to install sails-mongo (`npm install sails-mongo --save`). It's Showing Error :

```
~/newWebApp $ npm install sails-mongo --save

npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-24-generic
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "sails-mongo" "--save"
npm ERR! node v0.10.37
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.3

npm ERR! Cannot set property 'lodash' of undefined
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-24-generic
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "sails-mongo" "--save"
npm ERR! node v0.10.37
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.3

npm ERR! Cannot set property 'waterline-criteria' of undefined
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:

npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-24-generic
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "sails-mongo" "--save"
npm ERR! node v0.10.37
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.3

npm ERR! Cannot set property 'waterline-errors' of undefined
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:

npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-24-generic
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "sails-mongo" "--save"
npm ERR! node v0.10.37
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.3

npm ERR! Cannot set property 'fs-extra' of undefined
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:

npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-24-generic
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "sails-mongo" "--save"
npm ERR! node v0.10.37
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.3

npm ERR! Cannot set property 'waterline-cursor' of undefined
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:


npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/vgulp/newWebApp/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Running on 3.3.9 - works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its due to incompatibility of `sails-mongo` (or its dependencies)package with latest npm.

`sudo npm install npm@2.14.5 -g`

Then running

`npm install sails-mongo --save`

should solve your problem.